# How to deserialize json column value from DB to POJO with ignoring of unknown fields?

Tags: java, json, postgresql, hibernate

In my PostgreSQL database, there is a column in one of the tables that stores a third-party model in JSON format. When I work with an entity, I want to deserialize this JSON into the corresponding representation of this model (DTO, generated by OAS of another service).

**There is a Entity**

```
@Entity
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
public class A {
    // other fields

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(name = "jsonBody", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private SomeModel jsonBody;
}
```

Everything works fine until a third-party system updates its API and new attributes appear in the model. Then such an approach causes the error:

`Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "example"`

One possible solution would be to cut off all unknown attributes before saving to the database. But such an approach, it seems to me, does not guarantee that extraordinary situations will not happen when something extra will still get into the database. Plus, testers can accidentally (or not) add something extra to JSON. In general, I would like to find some kind of solution like
`@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`, which doesn't work, unfortunately.

Mapping JSON to a model works fine when I use `jackson.ObjectMapper`. Extra attributes are simply ignored.

All I could find on the Internet on the issue of ignoring unknown attributes are solutions for the `Web <-> Application` interaction, but not for the `Application <-> Database` case. Maybe I was asking Google incorrectly about this problem.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.6.3 if that's important

Comment: I didn't use that functionality myself yet, at least not the version that automatically parses json columns - so I can't tell whether there is an annotation that could be used. However, if you're working with Hibernate (which would be the default JPA provider that Spring Boot is providing) you could register a custom user type for `SomeModel.class`, use `ObjectMapper` there and configure it to ignore unknown properties.

Comment: This might also be interesting if you're using Hibernate: https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/11/18/using-spring-boot-objectmapper-with-hibernate-types/

Comment: @Thomas Yes, thanks. This looks like one of the possible solutions to the problem. If it turns out to be implemented in this way, I will add an answer to my question.

Comment: I would actually challenge this approach to just ignore unknown fields. If there are unknown fields, you maybe want to know about them in case you need to adjust your application. To parse the JSON and still know about unknown fields, you can implement a [`@Converter`](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-attribute-converters) which uses jackson and informs you if it encounters unknown fields.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer In fact, I am aware of all the API changes of the third-party system. They notify us about it. But it is not always possible to roll out the update to the prod in time (before them) to avoid errors. Therefore, I am looking for a way to protect the application from such a problem. So, a simple ignoring is enough for me, i think